# Counting a value's matches in 2 columns, counting separately

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a single table (call it Results) like this, with scores from a tournament:

```
id | Winner | Loser | Score
---+--------+-------+------
1    Bob      Joe     4
2    Roy      Mary    3
3    Joe      Roy     6
4    Mary     Bob     1
5    Ellen    Roy     9
6    José     Roy     2
7    Joe      Bob     7
```

What I want to do is to count the number of times each name is a winner, and each time they are a loser, and order it descending by number of games played:

```
Name | Wins | Losses | NumberGames
-----+------+--------+------------
Roy    1     3         4
Bob    1     2         3
Joe    2     1         3
Mary   1     1         2
Ellen  1     0         1
José   1     0         1
```

Better yet, I would like to order it descending by the percentage of games won divided by the total games played (wins plus losses).

I don't want to hard code any names, e.g. Winner = "Bob".

I know how to formulate a query to count each individual column, but I haven't figured out how to create 3 distinct counts and do a group by the name.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is to count the number of times each name is a
>   winner, and each time they are a loser, and order it descending by
>   number of games played:

This query works by generating a unique name list based on the Winner and Loser columns with the query.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT
  Results.Winner AS name
 FROM 
  Results

UNION 

SELECT
 DISTINCT
  Results.Loser AS name
 FROM 
  Results
```

And LEFT JOIN's that unique name list with Winner and Loser COUNT's to get the Wins and Loses.

**Query**

```
SELECT
   Results_Wins_Losses.name
 , Results_Wins_Losses.Wins 
 , Results_Wins_Losses.Losses 
 , (Results_Wins_Losses.Wins + Results_Wins_Losses.Losses) AS NumberGames
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
     unique_result_names.name
   , (
      CASE
         WHEN results_wins.Wins IS NULL
         THEN 0
         ELSE results_wins.Wins
       END
      ) AS Wins 
   , (
      CASE
         WHEN results_losses.Losses IS NULL
         THEN 0
         ELSE results_losses.Losses
       END
      ) AS Losses   
  FROM ( 
    SELECT
     DISTINCT
      Results.Winner AS name
     FROM 
      Results

    UNION 

    SELECT
     DISTINCT
      Results.Loser AS name
     FROM 
      Results 

  ) AS unique_result_names

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
       Results.Winner
     , COUNT(*) AS Wins
    FROM  
     Results
    GROUP BY
     Results.Winner
  ) AS results_wins 
  ON
   unique_result_names.name = results_wins.Winner

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
       Results.Loser
     , COUNT(*) AS Losses
    FROM  
     Results
    GROUP BY
     Results.Loser
  ) AS results_losses
  ON
   unique_result_names.name = results_losses.Loser
) AS Results_Wins_Losses
ORDER BY 
 NumberGames DESC
```

**Results**

```
|  name | Wins | Losses | NumberGames |
|-------|------|--------|-------------|
|   Roy |    1 |      3 |           4 |
|   Bob |    1 |      2 |           3 |
|   Joe |    2 |      1 |           3 |
|  Mary |    1 |      1 |           2 |
| Ellen |    1 |      0 |           1 |
|  José |    1 |      0 |           1 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68abe/33

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
SELECT  Name,
        SUM(Wins) AS Wins,
        SUM(Losses) AS Losses,
        SUM(Wins) + SUM(Losses) AS NumberGames
    FROM  
      (
        SELECT  winner AS Name, COUNT(*) AS Wins, 0 AS Losses
            FROM  Results
            GROUP BY  winner
        UNION  ALL 
        SELECT  loser AS Name,  0 AS Wins, COUNT(*) AS Losses
            FROM  Results
            GROUP BY  loser 
      )
    ORDER BY 4 DESC
```